# Swift : cannot convert return expression of any view to return type some view

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I don't know what I have this error : cannot convert return expression of any view to return type some view

I try some things but nothing nothing worked... And I found nothing on the web

Thanks for your help...

```
    struct LoginView: View {

    @Binding var showCreateAccount: Bool

    @State private var email = ""
    @State private var password = ""
    @State private var formOffset: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var presentPasswordRecoverySheet = false


    var body: some View {

         VStack {

            VStack(spacing: 40) {

                Image("Logo")

                Text("Login").font(.title).bold()

                VStack {
                    RoundTextfield(value: self.$email, placeholder: "Email", icon: Image(systemName: "at"),
                                    onEditingChanged: { flag in withAnimation { self.formOffset = flag ? -150 : 0 } })

                    RoundTextfield(value: self.$password, placeholder: "Password", icon: Image(systemName: "lock"), isSecure: true,
                                    onEditingChanged: { flag in withAnimation { self.formOffset = flag ? -150 : 0 } })

                    BasicButton(text: "Login") {}
                }


                Button(action: { withAnimation(.spring() ) { self.showCreateAccount.toggle() } } )
                {
                  HStack { Text("Don't have an account? Sign up.").accentColor(Color.accentColor) }
                }


                Button(action: { self.presentPasswordRecoverySheet.toggle() } )
                {
                  HStack { Text("Forgot your password?").accentColor(Color.purple) }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$presentPasswordRecoverySheet)
                    { RecoverPasswordView(presentPasswordRecoverySheet: self.$presentPasswordRecoverySheet) }

            }
            .padding()
            .offset(y: self.formOffset)

        }
    }
```

This is my BasicButton code, but I think this is not the problem

```
    struct BasicButton: View {
    var text = "Next"
    var action: (()->()) = {}

    var body: some View {
      Button(action: {
        self.action()
      }) {
        HStack {
            Text(text)
                .bold()
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical)
                .accentColor(Color.white)
                .background(Color("accentColor"))
                .cornerRadius(30)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct BasicButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        BasicButton()
    }
```

When I remove the two button function for create account and forgot password, the code can build

Comment: Move pieces of this view into subviews until it points you to the precise location of your error. I suspect it's related to RoundTextfield and BasicButton since those are not standard types and you haven't shown their implementation. I am very suspicious of the phrase "any view" in your question, since that doesn't look like the error that Swift generally prints (though the compiler has changed a bit and I may just not have seen this error before). Is this precisely the error message?

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly the error message : cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyView' to return type 'some View'

----------------------------------------

CompileDylibError: Failed to build LoginView.swift

Compiling failed: cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyView' to return type 'some View'

/Users/kevin/Desktop/WorkIn/WorkIn/Authentification/LoginView.swift:24:10: error: cannot convert return expression of type 'AnyView' to return type 'some View'
         AnyView(VStack {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: "AnyView" is not precisely the same as "any view." That is exactly the difference I was expecting. ("any view" would require a new feature that has been proposed, but I did not think had been implemented yet.)

Comment: Sounds like you made good progress with removing things and then it builds. Keep removing and adding things until you find the smallest code that triggers the problem. Then post that code in a way that we can run it in a playground (though typically by the time you've done that, you'll find your mistake.) Without actually showing us the code, we're just guessing, which is not useful to any of us.

Comment: I have found : when I remove the two .accentColor of the two button on loginView, build run. But I don't know why

Comment: Excellent. If you've minimized it to something you can post (in a way that we can reproduce it), I'm certain we can help you. As before, we can't guess at the code you don't provide. We need an example, as small as possible, that demonstrates the problem, along with the precise error you're receiving (you haven't updated the question to fix the fact that you spelled the message incorrectly; most people won't read then entire comment thread).

Comment: I've hit the same problem myself when using 'accentColor'. Are you able to make a test for others to reproduce?

Comment: It can be various issues in this moment. There is some type of error to find though. For me it was that I copied and pasted some Color Extensions from another project, and the color palettes did not exist, I only had to delete them.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve been fiddling with the same error all day. There’s no issues when building/running normally. It's very strange. I even tried commenting out almost all of the code in my view except for one small piece of it and I’m still hitting a problem with `.font(.title)` . Amazingly, if I try running the same code in a new project, no problem. Also if I just comment out that line setting the font type the preview compiles and shows up.

And the errors being reported are basically non-sense, they’re not even on the right line.

So I guess the preview feature is just riddled with bugs still. Hopefully it improves soon. Feels like the initial rollout of Swift where people started adopting and using it faster than Apple was able to fix it. Or rather, Swift was probably released before the tooling was ready for it. Seems to be the same case here with SwiftUI.

Comment: Having the same problem with `.foregroundColor(_:)` and `.font(_:)`